# Set Custom Mouse Cursor on Windows 10 Universal App UWP

Tags: c++, uwp, cursor, mouse

How to set a mouse cursor from programmatically provided RGBA 8-bit per channel (32-bit total data) in a Win 10 UWP app?

In the documentation I see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.corecursor
The only way I see is to use a resource integer ID embedded in an application.

However I'm not interested in that.
What I need is to create a new cursor on the fly from the following parameters:

```
int width
int height
int hot_spot_x
int hot_spot_y
byte *rgba_data
```

I'm using C++

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devfish/2012/08/01/customcursors-in-windows-8-csharp-metro-applications/

Comment: like I said I'm not interested in using cursors made from resources, but need to dynamically generate them in the code while the app is running.

Comment: You can use it that write a new cur in file and load it.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not going to write a file every time I want to use a new cursor from memory, also I'm not even sure something like that would work, because the constructor accepts an integer resource ID and not a file path.
If there's no real API for such a function, then I'm asking Microsoft to add it.

Comment: Sorry for necrobump, but I really need the same feature. How have you done it please ?

Comment: you can't count on Microsoft to do anything